# Не получается связать сигнал и слот

Tags: c++, qt

В главном окне имеется чекбокс. В документации сказано, что при изменении состояния чекбокса, испускается сигнал stateChanged(int state), где state - текущее состояние кнопки. Мне нужно передать это состояние в слот, принадлежащий дочернему окну.

Пытался сделать следующим образом:
`connect(ui->IDE, SIGNAL(stateChanged(state)), m_CAN_Settings, SLOT(idStateChanged(state)))`

Но выдаёт предупреждение:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QCheckBox::stateChanged(state)
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'IDE')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'CAN_Settings')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connect(ui->IDE, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), m_CAN_Settings, SLOT(idStateChanged(int)))
```

А вообще, чтобы подобные конструкции с ошибками даже не компилировались, испольуйте т.н. [новый синтаксис](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax/ru)